# how to create more then one submit_url in ui_component Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, uicomponent, backend

I need to submit data from ui_component to another class so I created two buttons and on one I set the submit_url and works perfectly but in other class I cannot get the data to perform some functionalities. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Submit URL is picked up automatically. You can add additional URLs in the data provider and they can be accessed by `${ $.provider }.myCustomUrl`

Comment: `${ $.provider }.myCustomUrl` Sir where to write this code?